# Which of the following commands can change the ownership of WordPress directory to www-data (for Apache)?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, sudo

Which of the following commands can change the ownership of WordPress directory to www-data (for Apache)?

> sudo chown -Rf www-data *
>
> chown -Rf www-data *
>
> sudo crown -Df www-data *
>
> Alldo chown -Rf www-data *

Answer (score 0):

the "sudo" prefix ensures it runs as root - this should definitely run as root. If you are already logged in as root, sudo does nothing.

chown does not have a `-D` option (-Rf really means -R -f)

As far as I'm aware, there is no "crown" or "alldo" command.

The first one, `sudo chown -Rf www-data *` is the best answer, the second one will work if you're root.

BEWARE! that this opens up a big security risk - if there is any flaw in wordpress (and you can safely assume that there is), then the above command may let an attacker upload scripts to your server and run them, or make changes to any of your wordpress files.

Answer (score 0):

Best is set owner and group for wordpress directory. For me works:

```
sudo chown -Rf www-data:www-data /wpdirectory
```